# OR expression in regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, or-operator

I am trying to use a regular expression for a message that has a temperature at the end of it. An example of a whole message looks like this:

```
RH= 12.1 %RH T= -3.5 'C
```

If it isn't obvious, the temperature (and part relevant to this question) is `T = -3.5 'C`. I want to capture either `C` or `F` at the end. Right now I have this expression:

```
"RH=\\s*(?<1>[^\\s]*)\\s%RH T=\\s*(?<2>[^\\s]\\s*'\\w)"
```

But that will capture any alphanumeric character at the end. How do I change the last `'\\w'` at the end to say, "only `C` or `F`?"?

Comment: Hint: Use verbatim strings and conserve precious and rare backslashes:  `@"RH=\s*(?<1>[^\s]*)\s%RH T=\s*(?<2>[^\s]\s*'[CF])"`

Comment: Another way to specify OR is `|` (e.g. `(C|F)`), but character class is better in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): instead of `\\w`, write `[CF]`.

Comment: When I do that and change it to "RH=\\s*(?<1>[^\\s]*)\\s%RH T=\\s*(?<2>[^\\s]\\s*'\\w)", it tell matches characters that aren't C or F. So far it has matched a,1, and even _.

Comment: @Sterling: I don't understand: it looks like you *haven't* changed the `\\w` to `[CF]`?

Comment: Oh, pasted the wrong expression - RH=\\s*(?<1>[^\\s]*)\\s%RH T=\\s*(?<2>[^\\s]\\s*'[CF])

Comment: Nevermind, nevermind, was misreading my output. This is indeed working!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if provided formt is *definitive*, do not use complicated regex, but simple:

```
int index = data.LastIndexOf('\''); //index of last ' symbol
data.Substring(index);
```

*Should* workk for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to replace the final `\\w` with `c|f`, meaning: either c or f.